# Refilling a BlockedQueue in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue, fill

So I have this loop

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //Look at everything on queue currently and pulls them into a list
        List<ElevatorCall> callsWaiting = new ArrayList<ElevatorCall>();
        queue.drainTo(callsWaiting);

        ElevatorCall nextDestination = getBestOption(callsWaiting);


        System.out.println("Picked Person(" + nextDestination.getPerson().getId() + ") as best option");

        //Work on this section
        if(nextDestination != null)
        {
            sortCallsByShortestDistanceAndDirection(workQueue, nextDestination.getDirection());

            boolean arrived = moveTowards(nextDestination);

            while(!arrived)
            {
                //Check for new calls
                List<ElevatorCall> newCalls = new ArrayList<ElevatorCall>();
                queue.drainTo(newCalls);

                checkFloorForCallsAndAddToElevator(workQueue);
                sortCallsByShortestDistanceAndDirection(newCalls, nextDestination.getDirection());

                arrived = moveTowards(nextDestination);
            }
            arrived = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want it to keep going around and finding the destination floors. However, when it finds the first destination floor the loop ends, because when it goes back to the top, the queue.drainTo(callsWaiting) doesn't work because the queue has already been emptied. I think I need to refill it after I set arrived to false, however I'm not sure how to do this.
Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what is your getBestoption does. Before going while loop if you have 3 requests ( 7th floor , 8th floor ,20thfloor) in you queue.

```
while(true)
{
    //Look at everything on queue currently and pulls them into a list
    List<ElevatorCall> callsWaiting = new ArrayList<ElevatorCall>();
    queue.drainTo(callsWaiting);

    ElevatorCall nextDestination = getBestOption(callsWaiting);
```

in the above section you are retriving all requests and placed in calls waiting ( 3 ElevatorCall objects in callswaiting. and when you get nextDestination ( i am assuming you are picked the 7th floor if your current elevator at 5th floor and remove the 7th floor request from callswaiting. and then process the 7th floor request. by remaining lines. But when / how are you addressing other two request in callswaiting ? 
Instead of if condition

```
 //Work on this section
    if(nextDestination != null)
```

have loop there , will solve your problem. like

```
while (nextDestination != null) {
       sortCallsByShortestDistanceAndDirection(workQueue, nextDestination.getDirection());

        boolean arrived = moveTowards(nextDestination);

        while(!arrived)
        {
            //Check for new calls
            List<ElevatorCall> newCalls = new ArrayList<ElevatorCall>();
            queue.drainTo(newCalls);

            checkFloorForCallsAndAddToElevator(workQueue);
            sortCallsByShortestDistanceAndDirection(newCalls, nextDestination.getDirection());

            arrived = moveTowards(nextDestination);
        }
        arrived = false;
        nextDestination = getBestOption(callsWaiting);
```

}

Note** , picked the nextDestination from getBestoption and assumed getBestoption return null if the passing collection is empty.